# Adding to global variable in javascript function returns NaN

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to add to a global variable in order to determine total file size from an ajaxfileupload. I've tried the two ways below but attachmentSize keeps returning NaN.  I've tried an if statement that checks for isNaN false, but variable still set to NaN.

```
var attachmentSize;
function onUploadComplete(sender, args) {
    attachmentSize += args.get_fileSize();
    attachmentSize = attachmentSize + args.get_fileSize();
}
```

Comment: `attachmentSize` is not initialized... initialize it to 0

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple I was missing,

Comment: great! have posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Initialize `attachmentSize` to a number (say 0).

Also, if you expect `args.get_fileSize()` to be a string (and not a number), then you can use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`:

```
var attachmentSize = 0;
function onUploadComplete(sender, args) {
    attachmentSize += parseFloat(args.get_fileSize());
    attachmentSize = attachmentSize + parseFloat(args.get_fileSize());
}
```

Cheers!